# Combine outputs of a function for each index in a for loop in R

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I have created a function which completes a calculation based on data from two data frames for an individual.
I want to complete that function for each individual and combine all the outputs in a data frame and export to .csv
Currently the output .csv only has data for person 34, none of the other.
I've noted that when I run this it creates an object `ID`, which is just the numeric 34. It seems to be only holding on to the last ID in data$ID.

How can I create an output with results for all persons?

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(date)

screen_function = function(x){
 # Select each person and get necessary inputs
   data = data%>%filter(ID == x)
  demogs = demogs %>% filter (P_ID == x)
  data$Age =  demogs$Age
 
   data$result = data$test * data$Age
   
   data$Date = as.Date(data$Date,format='%d/%m/%Y') # ensures date column is in correct format
   
 # only include tests from most recent 12-24 months and only proceed if test in last 12 months  
   Recent_12m  = data %>% filter(between(Date, today() - years(1), today()))   
   Recent_24m  = data %>% filter(between(Date, today() - years(2), today()))   
   
   if ((nrow(Recent_12m)) > 0) {           
      
     data = rbind(Recent_12m,Recent_24m) 
     
     Recent_12m$min_date = min(Recent_12m$Date) 
     Recent_12m$Date = as.Date(Recent_12m$Date,format='%d/%m/%Y') 
     Recent_12m$min_date = as.Date(Recent_12m$min_date,format='%d/%m/%Y') 
     
     Recent_24m$min_date = min(Recent_24m$Date)
     Recent_24m$Date = as.Date(Recent_24m$Date,format='%d/%m/%Y') 
     Recent_24m$min_date = as.Date(Recent_24m$min_date,format='%d/%m/%Y') 
     
    
     Recent_12m$Period = interval(Recent_12m$min_date, Recent_12m$Date) 
     Recent_12m$Years = as.numeric(Recent_12m$Period, unit = "years")   
     Recent_24m$Period = interval(Recent_24m$min_date, Recent_24m$Date)  
     Recent_24m$Years = as.numeric(Recent_24m$Period, unit = "years")    
     
     # Latest result
     Last = filter(Recent_12m, (Recent_12m$Date == max(Date)))
     
     # linear regression model
     Reg_12month <- lm(result ~ Years, data=Recent_12m) 
     Reg_24month <- lm(result ~ Years, data=Recent_24m) 
     
     
     info = c(x, round(Last$result, digits=1), round(Reg_12month$coefficients["Years"], digits = 1), round(Reg_24month$coefficients["Years"], digits = 1)) 
     newdf = data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 4))
      colnames(newdf) = c("ID", "Latest result",    "Trend 12month",    "Trend 24 month")
      newdf= rbind(newdf, info)
      write.csv(newdf, "filepath.csv")
     }
}


Date= sample(seq(as.Date('2019/11/01'), as.Date('2020/11/01'), by="day"), 12)
ID= c(12,12,12,450,450,450,1,1,1,34,34,34)
test= rnorm(12, mean=150, sd=60)
data= data.frame(ID, Date, test)

P_ID = c(1,12,34,450)
Age = c(50,45,60,72)
demogs =  data.frame(P_ID, Age)


persons = unique(data$ID)

for(ID in persons){
  
  screen_function(paste("", ID,"", sep=""))
}
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: the file `filepath.csv` gets created as you expected. The function doesn't show any output because the last line of the function is a `write.csv` instance. What  was your expected result?

Comment: Sorry, I do get the file `filepath.csv`; I had not set correct working directory. But I only get a row of data for `ID ==34`, not for any of the others. I will edit the question.

Comment: It shows only the last one coz with write.csv you overwrite what is written before, don’t you?

Comment: So how can I write a .csv that retains previous data?

Comment: set `append = TRUE` in `write.csv`. Also it's better if you set `col.names = FALSE` because otherwise colnames are written every time. You could set up your script in way like this: `append <- file.exists("filepath.csv"); write.csv(newdf, "filepath.csv", append = append, col.names = !append)`. If the file exists, you just append new results without col.names, otherwise you leave the col.names (and you don't append, coz the file doesnt exist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've got around this by using a pre-made .csv, instead of creating a new dataframe. The .csv just contains a single row of 4 columns, with random entries in each cell.

```
newdf= read.csv(file = "filepath.csv")
info =  c(x, round(Last$result, digits=1), round(Reg_12month$coefficients["Years"], digits = 1), 
                                        round(Reg_24month$coefficients["Years"], digits = 1)) 
newdf= rbind(Summary, patient_info)
colnames(newdf) = c("ID", "Latest result",    "Trend 12month",    "Trend 24 month")
newdf= distinct(newdf, ID, .keep_all = TRUE)
write.csv(Summary, "filepath.csv", row.names = FALSE)}}
```